# Close review with filter = java and question about LINQ and C#

Tags: bug, tags, review-audits, filtering

Reviewing closed questions is awesome because you help the community, and the sanity check is awesome, but could I propose an enhancement to the algorithm that proposes the "Congratulations questions"?

That is because it is obvious a question is a test and not a real question. The giveaway is the tag in the question. My filter is about Java, and the question proposed is C#, [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

My proposal is that "test question" be picked up by the same type as the filter.

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5570013?filter-tags=java

After I passed:

> [image]

Comment: Not a bug.  This is [meta-tag:status-bydesign].  And this has been discussed previously on MSE... [Audits bug in the filtered review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204639/audits-bug-in-the-filtered-review-queue)

Comment: Good laugh "For technical reasons we aren't querying for audits with filters enabled"

Comment: Neither of the proposed duplicates give the reason clearly, but I suspect that if audits did respect filters, there are lots of filters where there would be no available audit questions, and a whole bunch of people would never be audited.

Comment: If you can't find one, then default to the lame current behavior. But I highly doubt that most tags won't have closed and still open questions that could be used. In any case, at least Java, C, C# should have PLENTY to pick from.